# Let Meteor templatehelper return true when value is in array or in propery

Tags: meteor

I have a handlebar #if helper in my HTML, so I can show some button only to the first player in my game.

detailssubmit.html

```
{{#if owner}}
 show this text
{{/if}}
```

My Game Collection:

```
{_id: id, 
 active: true, 
 players: [id, id]
 owner: id
}
```

In my helper my owner function always returns false.

```
Template.DetailsSubmit.helpers({
    details: function()  {
        return GameDetails.find({gameId: this._id})

    },

    owner: function() {
        var game = Games.find({_id: this._id});
        var id = Meteor.userId();
        // #1 try
        return (game.owner === id)
        // #2 try
       return ( _.first(game.players) === id )
    }
})
```

Am i missing something. My data is available in my browser if I use

```
Games.find().fetch()
```

so the available data should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findOne` rather than `find` when you just want one document. `Games.find(...)` will return a cursor, not a document.

```js
var game = Games.findOne({_id: this._id});
// or use this shorthand - findOne with a string argument finds by _id:
var game = Games.findOne(this._id);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I acces a certain property of this document. I cannot do game.owner or game.players[0] for example. This will lead to  a not defined error.

Comment: Then there is no document in that collection with that `_id`. Can you add `console.log(this)` to that helper and post what it says? Did you perhaps want `{_id: this.gameId}`?

Comment: Ok. So console.log(this) refers to the Games collection, which I have set in my Data function in my router. Maybe this creates the error, because: console.log(this.players) would output fine but console.log(game.players) will create an error. However, refering to this.players[0] still return an undefined error.

Comment: Can you post the exact output of `console.log(this)`? When you say it refers to the Games collection, what exactly do you mean (the entire collection, or just the one document?)

Comment: It refers to a unique document. I cannot paste it here nicely. But I've made different user accounts to test it. Each document in the games collection has max 2 users, and for the third player console.log(this) refers to an unique document with a unique _id. 

In my router I've set the data function as: Games.findOne(this.params._id)  which have set the this.

Comment: I can acces the properties in this manner: 
this.owner => returns an id, and _.first(this.players) => return the first value of the array. However this.players[0] doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.players)`?

Comment: console.log(this.players) will log the information in the players array, two unique ID's.